# How To Send Text Messages From Email?

Tags: c#, html

I have the folowing code on a form in my website

```
 <select class="form-control carrier" name="carrier" id="">
                        <option value="">* Who Is Your Phone Carrier?</option>
                        <option value="txt.att.net">AT&T</option>
                        <option value="tmomail.net">T-Mobile</option>
                        <option value="vtext.com">Verizon</option>
                        <option value="messaging.sprintpcs.com">Sprint</option>
                        <option value="vmobl.com">Virgin Mobile</option>
                        <option value="mmst5.tracfone.com">Tracfone</option>
                        <option value="mymetropcs.com">Metro PCS</option>
                        <option value="myboostmobile.com">Boost Mobile</option>
                        <option value="sms.mycricket.com">Cricket</option>
                        <option value="ptel.com">Ptel</option>
                        <option value="text.republicwireless.com">Republic Wireless</option>
                        <option value="tms.suncom.com">Suncom</option>
                        <option value="message.ting.com">Ting</option>
                        <option value="email.uscc.net">U.S. Cellular</option>
                        <option value="cingularme.com">Consumer Cellular</option>
                        <option value="cspire1.com">C-Spire</option>
                        <option value="vtext.com">Page Plus</option>
                    </select>
```

Then in the controller I save the number as follows

```
var pNumber = PhoneNumber.Replace("(", "");
            pNumber = pNumber.Replace(")", "");
            pNumber = pNumber.Replace("-", "");
            pNumber = pNumber.Replace(" ", "");


            var fullPhoneNumber = pNumber + "@" + carrier;
```

After it is saved in my database I send ti like a regular email

```
private void SendWebMailMessage(string to, string from, string subject, string body)
      {


          //create the mail message
          MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
          //set the FROM address
          mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
          //set the RECIPIENTS
          mail.To.Add(to);
          //enter a SUBJECT
          mail.Subject = subject;
          //Enter the message BODY
          mail.Body = body;
          //set the mail server (default should be smtp.1and1.com)
          SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.1and1.com");
          //Enter your full e-mail address and password
          smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("********", "*****");
          mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
          //send the message 
          smtp.Send(mail);
      }
```

The point of this is so I can sent texts to their phone from an email.
This works fine on my phone which is ATT but one of users who is using Verizon, complained that if the message is more than just a sentence or two part of it gets cut off. She says thus never happened to her before with her phone, other times if the message was to long it would just come in as two messages. What can be causing this problem?

Comment: Please show the code on how you are sending the email/text as that is where the problem will lie, not in the form itself.

Comment: Please see additions

Comment: You're still not showing any attempt at sending mail.  We're not here to write code for you. [ask]

Comment: Please See additions

Comment: Slowly we are getting there. How is the text sent? I am unsure what you mean by sending a text from an email.

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Send-a-Text-from-Email

Comment: A couple of things here. You may want to check with users of other carriers to see what they are getting; Another thing to keep in mind is that true SMS is still limited to 160 characters. I have seen Verizon issues before, but I cannot discuss